# place values by condition with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a three channel matrix and I want to place the value which is less than 27

```
a=numpy.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
a[a<27]=0
```

However, If I want to replace only on first channel, the way I can do is to write a for loop

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if a[i][j][0] < 27:
            a[i][j][0]=0
```

I am not sure how to do this with a more simple way.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
a=numpy.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
a[a[:,:,0]<27, 0]=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you were looking for this: `a[:,:,0][a[:,:,0]<27]=0`